# javax.xml.transform.Transformer ignoring prefixes?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to parse a very simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'>
    <openSearch:totalResults>100</openSearch:totalResults>
</root>
```

The stylesheet I am using is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                version="1.0" 
                xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <xsl:attribute name="total-results">
                <xsl:value-of 
                 select="atom:root/openSearch:totalResults"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works in libxslt, no problem. I am trying to perform the same task in java now, and I am trying to use the javax.xml.transform package to perform this. Instead of the expected result,  it provides an empty value for the total-results attribute. However when I change the value-of to this:

```
                <xsl:value-of select="root/totalResults"/>
```

It works. Changing the xml and the xslt is not an option. Is there a parameter I should be setting somewhere? The code is pretty straightforward:

```
InputSource xmlSource = new InputSource( new StringReader(xml) );

DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

// Use a Transformer for output
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();


StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(styleSheet));
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);

stringResult = writer.toString();
```

Comment: You say changing the XSLT isn't an option, but that XSLT is wrong.  You are using two namespace prefixes that are undefined, and one of those prefixes shouldn't be there.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the behavior you describe:  xsltproc does not accept the stylesheet you give, but raises a namespace error owing to the undefined prefix.  You want the smallest possible example that illustrates the behavior -- but not something smaller!

Comment: You are right. My problem was ultimately in the java code (See the accepted answer) but I will be more careful when posting code in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the stylesheet, you are missing the namespace declarations for "atom" and "openSearch".
The following works:

1. Add the "openSearch" namespace (copied from xml) in the stylesheet
2. Remove the "atom" namespace since there is no information on this
   namespace
3. Set the factory as namespace aware: `factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Here is the complete code in Scala (sorry I was too lazy parsing the xml and stylesheet from a file or doing string concatenation in Java):

```
  def testxsl = {
      val xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'>
    <openSearch:totalResults>100</openSearch:totalResults>
</root>
      """
      val styleSheet = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
        xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' 
        xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/'>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <results>
        <xsl:attribute name="total-results">
                <xsl:value-of select="root/openSearch:totalResults"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
        """
    val xmlSource = new InputSource( new StringReader(xml) );
    val factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    val builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    val document = builder.parse(xmlSource);

    // Use a Transformer for output
    val tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();


    val stylesource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(styleSheet));
    val transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(stylesource);

    val writer = new StringWriter();

    val source = new DOMSource(document);
    val result = new StreamResult(writer);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    writer.toString(); 
  }
```

Comment: +1 for point 3 - it's easy to forget that `DocumentBuilderFactory` is _not_ namespace aware by default.

Comment: But rather than change the factory to be namespace aware, don't supply the value as a DOMSource unless you have a very good reason. Supply a StreamSource and let the XSLT processor build the tree in its own preferred internal format, which will probably be much faster than using a DOM.

Comment: The DocumentBuilderFactory namespace setting was exactly where I was getting confused. I was able to address the issue once I was pointed in that direction.